# Meteor destroys template on parent re-render

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Hi I want to render same template with different data inside a meteor template using Meteor.render. My problem is whenever parent template re-renders it destroys template rendered using Meteor.render. I'm new to meteor and not sure is this the right way to do this thing. Please help. I'm sharing my test code:

**test.html**

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  <div style="margin: 10px;">
    <input type="button" id="render" value="Render">
    <input type="button" id="resize" value="Resize">
    <div id="placement" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #eee; width: {{width}}px; height: {{height}}px"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="temp">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
</template>
```

**test.js**

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.test.helpers({
    height: function() {
      return Session.get("size");
    },
    width: function() {
      return Session.get("size");
    }
  });

  Template.test.created = function() {
    Session.set("size", 200);
    Session.set("name", "Dal Chand");
  }

  Template.test.events({
    'click #render': function(event, template) {
      var frag = Meteor.render(function(){
        return Template.temp({name: Session.get("name")});
      });
      var el = document.getElementById('placement');
      if(el) el.appendChild(frag);
    },
    'click #resize': function(event, template) {
      var size = Session.get("size");
      Session.set("size", (size + 100) % 500 + 300);
    } 
  });
}
```

So the problem here is when I click on **Resize** button it removes **temp** template from the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you're looking to achieve, but you can make much better use of reactivity in the templates here, rather than using JS to insert new DOM elements, which will generally just get in the way of what Meteor is doing (as you have found).

Try:

```
...
<template name="test">
  <div style="margin: 10px;">
    <input type="button" id="render" value="Render">
    <input type="button" id="resize" value="Resize">
    <div id="placement" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #eee; width: {{width}}px; height: {{height}}px">
        {{#if renderTemp}}{{> temp}}{{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
...
```

and

```
if(Meteor.isClient){

Session.set('renderTemp', false);

  Template.test.helpers({
    height: function() {
      return Session.get("size");
    },
    width: function() {
      return Session.get("size");
    }
  });

  Template.test.helpers({
    renderTemp: function() {
      return Session.get('renderTemp');
    }
  })

  Template.test.created = function() {
    Session.set("size", 200);
    Session.set("name", "Dal Chand");
  }

  Template.temp.helpers({
    name: function() {
      return Session.get("name");
    }
  })

  Template.test.events({
    'click #render': function(event, template) {
      Session.set('renderTemp', true);
    },
    'click #resize': function(event, template) {
      var size = Session.get("size");
      Session.set("size", (size + 100) % 500 + 300);
    } 
  });
}
```

There are also ways you can achieve reactivity without having to declare `Session` variables, which can often be neater - see [here](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/vhdWPskmLjNDoqjYd).  If the behaviour on clicking "Render" needs to be more complex or there are circumstances under which you'd want to hide the `temp` Template again, just put the logic in the relevant event handlers.

**UPDATE:**
As a final point, it's not clear why you're using `Template.test.created`.  `Session` variables are available anywhere (on the client), so you're probably best setting these up somewhere at the top of the file rather than waiting for a template to be created, in case you try to reference `name` in some other piece of code and it hasn't yet been set the first time that piece of code runs (because templates are still being rendered).  Just a thought.